# Backbone render after initialize - initialize get's triggered to early?

Tags: backbone.js, initialization, render

I have a div#game.
In here I want some data from the server to appear.
So when I use the initialize function I request data from my server in my game model with an ajax call.

```
Game = Backbone.View.extend(
{
    id: 'game',

    initialize: function ()
    {
        this.model.on('getGame', function() {});
        this.model.getGame();
    }
}
```

Because a callback doesn't seem to work in backbone a trigger has to be made.
So the app listens to the trigger `getGame` which is triggerd when the data from the server has been returned and saved into a variable in the model.

So far so good, this all works. The only problem now is that I want my div#game to fadeIn when it's done appending all data from the getGame function.

But I think because off the model.on(trigger) the initialize function 'thinks' it's ready after running the getGame() function, without actually having the data from the server appended yet.

So the parent div#all running the following:

```
this.$el.append(new Game().el);
```

also 'thinks' the div#game is ready and appends the div#game to itself and gives it a fadeIn.

div#game doesn't contain the server data yet, so when it actually does come back the images and text pop into existence instead of fadeIn in nicely...

Does some one know how to resolve this problem?
Thanks in advance!

======================================================

SOLVED

The problem was in the asynchronous property of the $.get and $.post functions. This is why the initialize was ready before the results had come back from the server. I changed it into a $.ajax and made the async: false. Now it all loads in the order I programmed/want.

Thank you for your detaild explaination Tallmaris, it will come in handy for sure since I'll be using a lot of triggers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than having the `div#all` render and append the view to itself, you can pass it as a `parent` to the View:

```
this.gameView = new Game({parent: this});
```

Then in your `Game` view:

```
initialize: function (options)
  this.parent = options.parent
  {
    this.model.on('getGame', function() { this.$el.appendTo(this.parent); });
    this.model.getGame();
  }
```

Alternatively you could use a global Backbone event object like this:

```
window.vent = $.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
```

Now you have a global object (which you can name and put in any namespace as you like, don't just do it as in the code above), that you can use like this:

MAIN VIEW:

```
initialize: function () {
    vent.on("GameReady", function () 
      { 
        // fade in game view
      }); 
}
```

GAME VIEW:

```
initialize: function (options)
  this.parent = options.parent
  {
      this.model.on('getGame', function() { vent.trigger("GameReady"); });
      this.model.getGame();
  }
```

You can also pass parameters around. Read [here for more documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Events).

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, it looks good! =)

but how would the parent div#all know when to start the fadeIn?

And the 'this.parent' is an object, to be able to append you'd have to append to this.parent.$el right?

Comment: Yes, sorry, you will need `this.parent.$el`. The idea would be that the `Game` view could fade itself in: `this.$el.fadeIn()`. Alternatively, you can use a global Backbone event object. I will update the answer with that.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried some google searches and found that the problem was actually a lot simpler than I thought! The problem was in the asynchronous property of the $.get and $.post functions. This is why the initialize was ready before the results had come back from the server.

I changed it into a $.ajax and made the async: false. 

Now it all loads in the order I programmed.

Comment: Eheh ok... sorry, I skipped over the most obvious thing first :) Happy it works ok.